How to get RTL8812BU USB3 WIFI 1200AC adapter to detect as USB3 device?
The driver for the RTL88X2BU has been incorporated into the mainline kernel since 6.2.
Ubuntu 22.0.04 Kernel 6.15.0-44.
However when using this USB3 device it is instead detected as a 480M USB2 device and cannot reach full speed.  I have tested the device on the same hardware platform running Windows which identifies the device correctly as USB3.
$ lsusb -t
.
.
.
    |__ Port 5: Dev 9, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=rtw_8822bu, 480M

Is there some way I can force the device to be recognized as a USB3 device under Linux?
Update:
On the https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702 this driver states it defaults to USB2 mode and a modprobe option is required to make it a USB3 device:
# Note: To activate USB3 mode, change rtw_switch_usb_mode above to rtw_switch_usb_mode=1
options 88x2bu  rtw_switch_usb_mode=1

Ubuntu didn't seem to come with a conf file so I created a /etc/modprobe.d/88x2bu.conf with the above entry (copied from the github site)
However I'm not sure how to name the conf file or reference the driver properly (in the conf file).
lsmod lists these modules:
lsmod | grep rtw
rtw88_8822bu           12288  0
rtw88_usb              24576  1 rtw88_8822bu
rtw88_8822b           229376  1 rtw88_8822bu
rtw88_core            356352  2 rtw88_usb,rtw88_8822b
mac80211             1724416  2 rtw88_core,rtw88_usb
cfg80211             1323008  2 rtw88_core,mac80211

And lsusb -t list the driver as:
Port 5: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=rtw_8822bu, 480M

I tried changing the options name to all those above but never managed to get USB3 mode.

Do you have any other USB3 devices to check the port with? It might point at the drivers for the USB controller are incorrect

Yes USB3 thumbdrive.  I used the subject USB 3 device in the same port with Windows and everything works as expected.  I also tried the device in several ports and it is always seen as a USB2 device under linux and always as a USB3 device under Windows (on the same dual boot machine).

The answer as of this post (obtained from the driver maintainer) is the mainstream driver does not yet support USB3 mode.
USB3 mode is currently testing downstream and will be merged when stable.
I cloned the downstream driver and verified it enabled USB3 mode for this device.
https://github.com/morrownr/USB-WiFi
https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702/issues/227
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88

